# Differences between rjags and r2jags

Tags: r, jags, r2jags, rjags

I use both packages in order to do Bayesian analysis but there are some differences that I don't understand:

First of all the package `rjags` allows the adaptation phase, with the `jags.model` function, while the package `r2jags` does not have this phase, and with the function `jags` (or `jags.parallel`) begin to sample from the posteriori distribution. Is the adaptive phase included in that function, or the package `r2jags` does not consider it?

Secondly, in `rjags`, could I say that these two chunks of code are similar?

```
jmod <- jags.model(file="somefile.txt", data = data, n.chains=3)
update(jmod,100)
jsample <- coda.samples(jmod, n.iter=100, variable.names=par)
```

and

```
jmod <- jags.model(file="somefile.txt", data = data, n.chains=3)
jsample <- coda.samples(jmod, n.iter=200,n.burnin=100, variable.names=par)
```

that is, the burn-in phase with `update` function can be also done in `coda.samples` function? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`R2jags` is an over-the-top function for running `rjags`. It is meant to make it a bit easier to do some things as described in the package description like running until converged, or parallelising MCMC chains.

If you look at the `jags` function in `R2jags` (e.g. by looking at [the source code](https://github.com/cran/R2jags/blob/master/R/jags.R) or just entering `jags` without brackets into your R console), you will find the following calls near the end of the function (lines 151–177 on linked github version):

```
  m <- jags.model(model.file,
                  data     = data,
                  inits    = init.values,
                  n.chains = n.chains,
                  n.adapt  = 0 )

  adapt( m,
         n.iter         = n.adapt,
         by             = refresh,
         progress.bar   = progress.bar,
         end.adaptation = TRUE )

  samples <- coda.samples( model          = m,
                           variable.names = parameters.to.save,
                           n.iter         = ( n.iter - n.burnin ),
                           thin           = n.thin,
                           by             = refresh,
                           progress.bar   = progress.bar )
```

So `R2jags::jags` is compiling the model with `jags.model`, adapting it with `adapt`, then iterating and sampling from the posterior with `coda.samples`

Your two calls aren't exactly equivalent.
In the first you:

1. compile and adapt with `jags.model`,
2. update for 100 iterations with `update`, then
3. update and sample from the posterior for 100 iterations with `coda.samples`.

In the second you

1. compile and adapt with `jags.model`,
2. update and sample from the posterior for 200 iterations with `coda.samples`.

*I.e.*, you're posterior sample is from more iterations but there is no additional "burn-in" phase in method 2 after the adaptation implicit in `jags.model`. There is no use for `n.burnin` in `rjags`, only in `R2jags`; see the `coda.samples` call in the `jags` function code above, while earlier [on line 77](https://github.com/cran/R2jags/blob/master/R/jags.R), that function assigns `n.adapt <- n.burnin`.

Comment: So it's just an ensamble of functions. Thank you, very clear.

Comment: One of the great things about R is that it's pretty easy to look inside of functions and work out what they might be doing. Don't be scared to just plug a function name directly into the console to see the underlying code